# Legacy Appcelerator Project Skips Adding Modules

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've got a 3-year old Appcelerator Titanium project that I'm trying to build with a newer SDK (mainly to avoid having to install an older xCode to build against).  It was originally built with 3.1.x.  I've tried 5.x and 6.x with the same runtime error:

```
[ERROR] Script Error Couldn't find module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk for architecture: arm64
```

The module doesn't matter.  I can remove the `require` for that one, and it will fail at commonjs modules as well, like ti.cloud.  Also, I am 100% certain that the module is built with 64-bit support, as I've been using it for some years now.

There is a line in the build log:

```
[TRACE]  No native module libraries to add
```

And prior to that:

```
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 1.1.1 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/1.1.1
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 1.2.0 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/1.2.0
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 1.2.2 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/1.2.2
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 4.2.1 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/4.2.1
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 4.5.0 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/4.5.0
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 5.1.0 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/5.1.0
[DEBUG]  Detected iphone module: com.mirasense.scanditsdk 5.2.1 @ /Users/trey/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.mirasense.scanditsdk/5.2.1
```

So it knows the module is there, `build` doesn't know the project needs the modules.  I just can't figure out why.  I'm building this way:

```
appc run -p ios -T device
```

Build is successful, the error only happens at runtime.  Same thing building on the simulator, but for x86_64.

Here is the modules section of tiapp.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module>com.mirasense.scanditsdk</module>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
</modules>
```

Any insight?

Answer (score -1):

Older version of module doesn't support arm 64 bit architecture, therefore please download the latest com.mirasense.scanditsdk (scanditsdk) module from market this will resolve this issues,

Secondly if you are not using the module any more then remove it from tiapp.xml file and clean and rebuild project.

All the older versions of module you need to either regenerate or if available then download from git/appcelerator market.

This will resolve your problems.

Comment: You didn't read the question...  I have the most recent version of the module.  None of the modules are being copied into the build.